# extending angular e2e testing

Tags: angularjs, integration-testing

I have been using the Angular Scenario Runner for performing End To End tests on our codebase.

I am following:
http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.e2e-testing

Compared to frameworks such as capybara etc, the supplied matchers seem quite limited.

What options are available to help in End To End testing Angular Applications?

Answer (score 1):

The next tool for AngularJS will be [Protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor)

Answer (score 0):

you can use Selenium, of course.

One good thing that E2E does is to record all outgoing requests, so that it continues only after all of them are back with responses. This way you dont need to set a timer to check when your page is fully loaded. Not sure if Selenium supports that.